# How to write a Regex Pattern to identify words starting and ending with specific characters

Tags: java, regex

I want find words starting with @@_ and ending with _@@. Need to write it as a java Regex Pattern.

Example : abcd erhjr `@@_dhsdj_@@` dshdgj andaj edwyhu `@@_dgayw_@@` nssd.

Regex should find `@@_dhsdj_@@` and `@@_dgayw_@@`.

I tried using ,

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("@@_\b\S+?\b_@@").matcher(searchText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("@@_\\S*?_@@").matcher(searchText);
while (m.find()) {
    result.add(m.group(0));
}
```

`@@_\S*?_@@` will match `@@_`, then any 0 or more non-whitespace chars as few as possible and then `_@@`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bJQHHk/1) and the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/7EERXN).

You may consider splitting with whitespaces and then getting any item from the resulting array that starts with `@@_` and ends with `_@@`:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
// ...
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(searchText.split("\\s+"))
            .filter(i -> i.startsWith("@@_") && i.endsWith("_@@"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/vqCvBm).